# Why sympy lambdify function cannot identify numpy sum function and multiply function

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

**I want to use sympy and numpy to learning machine learning. Because symoy provides very convenient partial derivative calculation.
But in the process of use, I found that sympy lambdify function and can't identify the numpy sum function and multiply function.**

---

Take the following example

```
y_ = np.sum(np.dot(w,x)+b)
print(y_)
y_f = lambdify((w,x,b),y_,"numpy")
w_l = np.mat([1,1,1,1,1])
x_l= np.mat([1,1,1,1,1]).T
b_l = np.mat([0,0,0,0,0]).T
y_l = np.mat([6,6,6,6,6]).T
print(y_f(w_l,x_l,b_l))
```

```
b + w*x
[[5]
 [5]
 [5]
 [5]
 [5]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
y_ = np.multiply(w,x)+b
print(y_)
y_f = lambdify((w,x,b),y_,"numpy")
w_l = np.mat([1,1,1,1,1]).T
x_l= np.mat([1,1,1,1,1]).T
b_l = np.mat([0,0,0,0,0]).T
y_l = np.mat([6,6,6,6,6]).T
print(y_f(w_l,x_l,b_l))
```

```
b + w*x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/lijie/PycharmProjects/hw3/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(y_f(w_l,x_l,b_l))
  File "<lambdifygenerated-1>", line 2, in _lambdifygenerated
  File "C:\Users\lijie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 220, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
ValueError: shapes (5,1) and (5,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)
b + w*x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/lijie/PycharmProjects/hw3/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(y_f(w_l,x_l,b_l))
  File "<lambdifygenerated-1>", line 2, in _lambdifygenerated
  File "C:\Users\lijie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 220, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
ValueError: shapes (5,1) and (5,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)
```

As you can see,lambdify simply accepts lamda expressions without checking the operation notation. How to solve this problem. Thank you for your help

Comment: You can't multiply matrx of size 5x1 and 5x1, you need to use transpose of the second matrix.

Comment: You mean matrix dot multiplication. But I want to use multiplication

Comment: You mean parameter by parameter?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: The code I've shown you is two different pieces of code，In the first code,i used matrix dot multiplication,there was no erro，but the  function `np.sum` is not captured by `sympy.lambdify` . in the second code,i used `np.multiply`  and then it went wrong ,because `sympy.lambdify` translates it to `np.dot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing `numpy` and `sympy` can be tricky; add to that the potential confusions caused by `np.mat` instead of the base array type, `ndarray`.

### In sum

```
y_ = np.sum(np.dot(w,x)+b)
```

evaluates a python/numpy expression on sympy objects.  The result is a sympy expression `w*x+b`.  The sympy objects are scalars, so this doesn't encode any sort of matrix multiplication, or array summation.  The `multiply` expression evaluates the same way.

The `lambdify` expressions then translate the same `y_` to the same Python function.  And that evaluation depends on the dimensions and class of the `np.mat` arguments.

### details

Ignoring the `sympy` part for now:

```
In [310]: w = np.mat([1,1,1,1,1]) 
     ...: x= np.mat([1,1,1,1,1]).T 
     ...: b = np.mat([0,0,0,0,0]).T 
     ...: y = np.mat([6,6,6,6,6]).T                                             
In [311]: np.sum(np.dot(w,x)+b)                                                 
Out[311]: 25
In [312]: np.multiply(w,x)+b                                                    
Out[312]: 
matrix([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Because they are `np.mat`, both `w` and `x` are 2d:

```
In [316]: w.shape                                                               
Out[316]: (1, 5)
In [317]: x.shape                                                               
Out[317]: (5, 1)
```

`np.dot` of (1,5) with (5,1) is a (1,1) result:

```
In [313]: np.dot(w,x)                                                           
Out[313]: matrix([[5]])
```

and for `np.matrix`, `*` is defined as the `dot`:

```
In [314]: w*x                                                                   
Out[314]: matrix([[5]])
```

Elementwise:

```
In [315]: np.multiply(w,x)         # elementwise produces (5,5)                                   
Out[315]: 
matrix([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

`np.sum(np.dot(w,x)+b)` does the `dot`, then adds `b`, and ends with a `sum` over all elements.

`np.multiply(w,x)+b` does this multiply, adds `b`.  There's no `sum`.

### correction

Using the `w.T` that I missed the first time:

```
In [322]: np.multiply(w.T,x)                                                    
Out[322]: 
matrix([[1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1]])
In [323]: w.T*x                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-323-11ad839cfa88> in <module>
----> 1 w.T*x

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py in __mul__(self, other)
    218         if isinstance(other, (N.ndarray, list, tuple)) :
    219             # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors
--> 220             return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
    221         if isscalar(other) or not hasattr(other, '__rmul__') :
    222             return N.dot(self, other)

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (5,1) and (5,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)
```

`np.multiply` of (5,1) and (5,1) produces (5,1), element wise multiplication

`w.T*x` is matrix multiplication for `np.mat`, hence the `np.dot` error.

The use of `np.mat` is discouraged (if not formally depricated).  In `numpy` the addition of `matmul/@` eliminates its notational advantages.  Life is simpler in `numpy` if you stick with the base array class, `ndarray`.  I realize that `sympy` still uses a 2d matrix concept, with `*` as matrix multiplication.

### with sympy

In a `isympy` session, I find that I need to define `w,x,b` as symbols:

```
y_ = np.sum(np.dot(w,x)+b)
```

If `w,x,b` are just Symbols, they are scalars, not matrices or arrays.  Your `np.sum(np.dot(1,2)+4)`, `np.multiply(1,2)+4` and `1*2+4` all produce the same thing.  It's only when the variables are arrays, or `np.mat`, or maybe `sympy.Matrix` that the expressions are different.

The problem isn't with `lambdify`.  In both cases it is given the same `y_` (as verified by the `print(y_)`.  You get the error because the arguments are `np.mat`, and `*` is matrix multiplication.

With `x,y,z` symbols:

```
In [55]: f = lambdify((x,y,z),x*y+z, 'numpy')
```

Using `isympy` introspection:

```
In [56]: f??                                                                    
Signature: f(x, y, z)
Docstring:
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x, y, z)

Expression:

x*y + z

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x, y, z):
    return (x*y + z)


Imported modules:
Source:   
def _lambdifygenerated(x, y, z):
    return (x*y + z)
File:      ~/mypy/<lambdifygenerated-4>
Type:      function
```

Read the full documentation for `lambdify`. Note that it is basically a lexical substitution

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html

This documentation warns:

> **As a general rule, NumPy
>       functions do not know how to operate on SymPy expressions, and SymPy
>       functions do not know how to operate on NumPy arrays. This is why lambdify
>       exists: to provide a bridge between SymPy and NumPy.**

### sympify

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.sympify

says it uses `eval`.  With `x,y,z` defined as symbols:

```
In [66]: eval('np.dot(x,y)+z')                                                  
Out[66]: x⋅y + z

In [67]: eval('np.sum(np.dot(x,y)+z)')                                          
Out[67]: x⋅y + z

In [68]: eval('np.multiply(x,y)+z')                                             
Out[68]: x⋅y + z
```

In other words, it just passes the symbols to the numpy functions (and/or operators),

```
In [69]: np.dot(x,y)                                                            
Out[69]: x⋅y
```

`dot` turns its inputs into arrays:

```
In [70]: np.array(x)                                                            
Out[70]: array(x, dtype=object)

In [71]: np.dot(np.array(x), np.array(y))                                       
Out[71]: x⋅y
```

This works because symbols have '*' and '+' defined.

`sympy` docs warn that evaluating `numpy` does not 'know' anything about sympy objects. It treats them as object dtype arrays, which may or might not work:

```
In [72]: sin(x)       # sympy sin                                                          
Out[72]: sin(x)

In [73]: np.sin(x)        # numpy sin                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'sin'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-92f2c2d0df9d> in <module>
----> 1 np.sin(x)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable sin method
```

The `np.sin` does `np.sin(np.array(x))` and then delegates the action to a `sin` method of `x` - which does not exist.